# Android device connected via VPN (fritz.box) to local server has false IP address

Tags: vpn, local

I have a problem. I recently added a server running at home. I'm currently running lighttpd on it to host some private stuff. Therefore I restricted the access to my local network and my static IP address (VPN IP). To access my stuff on my android device I connect via VPN (fritz.box) to my local network.

Problem: The local server doesn't see my static IP address (VPN IP) but rather the IP address of the android device. In contrast checking http://www.whatismyip.com/ shows my static IP address (VPN IP).

```
Android Device 
  ---> VPN 
  ---> local server (sees public IP address of android device)

Android Device 
  ---> VPN 
  ---> whatismyip.com (sees IP address of VPN)
```

Comment: (1) I think there is an error in your schema: Android Device is found twice and no local server. (2) How do you look for IP addresses on the local server? It seems that you are looking using the network created by the physical adapter rather than using the virtual adapter created by the VPN (as also answered by @davidgo). (3) What is the operating system of the server and what exactly is its setup.

Comment: It would be extremely useful, to diagnose your problem, if you could scan your local network with **nmap** at a time when your Android phone is connected to your VPN. **nmap** must be downloaded, I do not know your OS but it exists for all OSes, could you please post the output of a simple **ping** scan here? TY.

Answer (score 0):

You have not indicated how this is a problem.

This behaviour would seem correct.  Rather then thinking about an IP address for a box, think of an IP address per Interface/Virtual Interface.  A VPN usually provides a virtual interface, and will [ by neccessity ] use that Interface for sending traffic.   (There are a some hacks, for some OS's, that will allow you to change the source address, but this is an advanced topic and goes hand-in-hand with a strong understanding and advanced routing setup).

If you are wanting to see the servers real-world IP address, the practical way would be to drop the VPN and use pinholing/port mapping on your router (fritz box ?).  My preferred way, however, would be to simply reconfigure the webserver to accept the VPN IP address.

Comment: The problem is that my local webserver does NOT see the VPN IP but rather the android device IP. (updated question)